# Sending mail with SMTP server owned by ABV.BG return timeout exception?

Tags: c#, email, smtp, smtpclient

Why example not work? Even [SMTP server](https://help.abv.bg/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-pop3-%D0%B8-smtp-%D1%81%D1%8A%D1%80/) is OK.

I setup Outlook just to test SMTP server. Everything is OK. I am able to send and receive mails.
The problem is with C# code. It is always return timeout exception. Even if i set Timeout to max int.

The SMTP server port is fine due to Outlook client is used without any problem. Just check link on the top to see configuration of the SMT server. The same options are used from the same network.

```
public void SendAbvBg(string message)
{
    var Smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.abv.bg", 465); 
    Smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;          
    Smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    Smtp.Timeout = 80000;
    Smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    Smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mail@abv.bg", "pass");
    
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    msg.Body = message;
    msg.From = new MailAddress("mail@abv.bg", "name");
    msg.To.Add("mail@abv.bg");
    msg.HeadersEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    msg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
    msg.Subject = "Form";
    msg.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    msg.Headers.Add("MIME-Version", "1.0");
    msg.Headers.Add("Content-Language", "en-us");

    try
    {
        Smtp.Send(message);               
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        // timeout exception
    }   
}
```

How is this possible? Standard Outlook pop/smtp work. The code - no! Why?
Apart of that, Outlook configuration timeout is 2 minutes.

I have try 5 minutes `Timeout = 300000` and still receive error:
Message = "**The operation has timed out.**"

The SMT server is owned by ABV.BG. It is a UNIX smtp very old server.
The client code and Outlook client is in the same office company network. The network not restrict any ports or policy. The Outlook work perfectly with the same configuration and options as code example. This is the prove that problem is not related with network, firewall or any other restriction. It is bug in the code.

[image]

Can it be the problem with default TargetName = "SMTPSVC/smtp.abv.bg"?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.targetname?view=net-5.0

The GMAIL is OK and it is not part of the current topic.
[image]

[image]

https://passport.abv.bg/app/profiles/sendtosupport/form?from=abv.bg

[https://passport.abv.bg](https://help.abv.bg/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-pop3-%D0%B8-smtp-%D1%81%D1%8A%D1%80/)

Test from https://www.smtper.net/
[image]

Comment: Perhaps it's taking longer than 80 seconds?

Comment: @Llama nope. With Outlook configuration timeout is 2 minutes.

Comment: 2 minutes is 120 seconds, not 80 seconds.

Comment: Are you inside a corporate network or outside?  Are you using the company outlook server or a different outlook server?   Inside a corporate network you cannot go outside the network to a different email server.  The firewall uses port forwarding to send all port 465 to the internal outlook proxy server.  The proxy server is looking at the default credentials and will not use a username and password.  So the only way this code will work in a corporate network is to use the outlook server in the network and use default credentials.

Comment: @jdweng the smt server is owned by ABV.BG. It is a UNIX smtp very old server.
The client code and Outlook client is in the same office company network. The network not restrict any ports or policy. The Outlook work perfectly with the same configuration and options as code example.

Comment: Does server still work?  If it is old, then the encryption port number 465 probably won't work.  Port 465 is a secure connection.  Unencrypted mode uses port 25.  Try port 25 instead of 465.  I suspect you get an error after 30 seconds which usually means you are timing out from not reaching the proxy or the credentials are wrong.  As I said when you have Outlook installed all port 465 automatically gets forwarded to the Proxy Server that check the outlook credentials.  You message is not going to get to the unix smtp email server.  Talk to you MIS experts at your company..

Comment: @jdweng, smtp server work perfectly with outlook. The same connections options was taken from outlook and used into/with code example. Port 465 ssl/tls options still work perfectly with Outlook.

Comment: I don't think it will work with ABV.BG.  First it is old which means is probably isn't using 465.  Second when you have outlook the network has port forwarding to the outlook proxy server.  So message will never reach the ABV.BG server.  As I said you have to talk to one of your MIS experts to confirm what I'm saying.  What you may need to do is setup an account on Outlook that will forward email to the ABV.BG.  I'm not an expert on working with the Outlook Proxy Server.  Just know it exists and tried to bypass to get to GMAIL.  Never was able to get it to work.  The firewall block the port.

Comment: @jdweng, first GMAIL smtp and send mail is working perfectly. You need to use Google mail api, verify app and set gmail send scope access to use Oauth2 autentification. How GMAIL is related to the current problem? Why simple outlook client connect to proxy if never set it in my network? This not have any logic. 

Apart of all this, if you want to use gmail directly you need to disable security to simple pass in your security profile.  It is one simple toggle button and that is all. Still the main topic is ABV.BG servers not Gmail.

Comment: If GMAIL is working, than port forwarding is not being used.  You never said GMAIL was working.  Most companies block port 465 so hackers cannot get to the email server.  So issue must be the port number 465 is not supported in server and I would try port 25.  Also check error messages in the email account which may give some clues.  For example the outbox could be full.  Are any applications working with the server?  You may want from cmd.exe>Ping Server_Name to make sure you have a route.

Comment: Why, we continue with GMAL?

Less secure app access
Some apps and devices use less secure sign-in technology, which makes your account vulnerable. You can turn off access for these apps, which we recommend, or turn it on if you want to use them despite the risks. Google will automatically turn this setting OFF if it’s not being used. Learn more

Comment: The server port is OK due to Outlook is used without any problem. Just check link on the top to see configuration of the SMT server.

Comment: Also, the smtp server is not mine. It is owned by private company.  My internal net is OK. Port is not blocked.

Comment: Did you try telnet to see if you can reach the SMTP server? Open a DOS prompt and do: `telnet smtp.abv.bg 465` you can also try the port 25 `telnet smtp.abv.bg 25` do you get a connection ?

Comment: This is public server. You can also try on your side.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a class to test SMTP access. Simple test call the `SmtpSeverProbe(...)` method with your data. You will receive the Email on success. Will test the normal ports 25,465,587 will test SSL.

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace CommonCore.Tests
{
    // Based in:
    // https://gist.github.com/xamlmonkey/4737291

    //Normal port 25 text,465 SSL,587 text then STARTSSL


    /// <summary>
    /// For Testing access to SMTP server. 
    /// </summary>
    public static class SmtpTests
    {


        static int connectionTimeout = 1300;

        /// <summary>
        /// Tests RELAY, Try to send email port 25 with and without StartSSl, port 465 with SSL, Port 587 with StartSSL.
        /// Returns a resume Log, but you have a 'out string log' variable with details.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="login"></param>
        /// <param name="password"></param>
        /// <param name="server">To test SSL use a name that exists in the Server Certificate, For SSL avoid a IP</param>
        /// <param name="to">Accepts all formats: ...@... or  "......." &lt;....@....&gt;</param>
        /// <param name="msg">Message in the body</param>
        /// <param name="log">very detailed Log</param>
        /// <param name="error">Only Errors Log</param>
        /// <param name="from"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string SmtpServerProbe(string login, string password, string server,
            string to, string msg, out string log, out string error, string from = null)
        {
            //Normal port 25 text,465 SSL,587 text then STARTSSL

            string resume = "";
            error = "";
            log = Environment.NewLine;
            string _resume = "";
            string _error = "";

            int port;
            bool forceSsl;

            from = from ?? "\"Test Email\" <test@email.com>";

            bool _sendok = false;

            System.Net.Mail.MailAddress addr = null;
            try
            {
                addr = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(from);
            }
            catch
            {
                error = "'from' email address is incorrect.";
                log += "!! Error : " + error;
                resume = Environment.NewLine + $"[FAIL] 'from' incorrect format > '{from}'" + Environment.NewLine;
                return resume;
            }

            try
            {
                addr = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(to);
            }
            catch
            {
                error = "'to' email address is incorrect.";
                log += "!! Error : " + error;
                resume = Environment.NewLine + $"[FAIL] 'to' incorrect format > '{to}'" + Environment.NewLine;
                return resume;
            }

            //Test Relay
            port = 25;
            forceSsl = false;
            log += "----------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine +
                "Testing RELAY." + Environment.NewLine +
                "(user is not authenticated, email is sento to 'test@gmail.com')" + Environment.NewLine;
            _sendok = Tests.SmtpTests.ScanSMTP("", "", server, port, forceSsl, "\"Test Email\" <test@email.com>", "test@gmail.com", "Relay Test", out string _log, out _resume, out _error);
            if (_sendok)
            {
                resume += "SERVER IS ACCEPTING RELAY THAT'S VERY BAD IDEIA";
                resume += Environment.NewLine + $" (maybe it has an exception to this Host or IP '{System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()}')";
                log += _log + Environment.NewLine;
                log += "----------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine + " SERVER IS ACCEPTING RELAY THAT'S VERY BAD IDEIA" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            else
            {
                log += "----------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine + " SERVER is not accepting Relay, that's good." + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
            }

            //TEST SMTPS
            port = 465;
            forceSsl = true;
            log += Environment.NewLine + "__________________________________" + Environment.NewLine +
                $"Testing port {port} / force SSL={forceSsl}";
            _sendok = Tests.SmtpTests.ScanSMTP(login, password, server, port, forceSsl, from, to, msg, out _log, out _resume, out _error);
            log += _log;
            error += Environment.NewLine + _error;
            resume += _resume;

            //TEST SMTP with STARTSSL
            port = 25;
            forceSsl = false;
            log += Environment.NewLine + "__________________________________" + Environment.NewLine +
                $"Testing port {port} / try STARTSSL=true";
            _sendok = Tests.SmtpTests.ScanSMTP(login, password, server, port, forceSsl, from, to, msg, out _log, out _resume, out _error);
            log += _log;
            error += Environment.NewLine + _error;
            resume += _resume;

            //TEST SMTP no STARTSSL
            port = 25;
            forceSsl = false;
            log += Environment.NewLine + "__________________________________" + Environment.NewLine +
                $"Testing port {port} / try STARTSSL=false";
            _sendok = Tests.SmtpTests.ScanSMTP(login, password, server, port, forceSsl, from, to, msg,
                out _log, out _resume, out _error,
                true, false);
            log += _log;
            error += Environment.NewLine + _error;
            resume += _resume;

            //Test port 587 with STARTSSL
            port = 587;
            forceSsl = false;
            log += Environment.NewLine + "__________________________________" + Environment.NewLine +
                $"Testing port {port} / try STARTSSL=true";
            _sendok = Tests.SmtpTests.ScanSMTP(login, password, server, port, forceSsl, from, to, msg, out _log, out _resume, out _error);
            log += _log;
            error += Environment.NewLine + _error;
            resume += _resume;

            return resume;

        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Tests the SMTP server and try to send a test Email
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="login"></param>
        /// <param name="password"></param>
        /// <param name="server">Server DNS name</param>
        /// <param name="port"></param>
        /// <param name="forceSsl"></param>
        /// <param name="from"></param>
        /// <param name="to"></param>
        /// <param name="msg">Message to send to the body</param>
        /// <param name="log">Detailed Log</param>
        /// <param name="resume">Resumed Log</param>
        /// <param name="error">Erro Log</param>
        /// <param name="checkcertificate">Check if SSL Certificate in the Server is acceptable</param>
        /// <param name="trystartssl">try to send the command STARTTLS</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool ScanSMTP(string login, string password, string server, int port, bool forceSsl,
            string from, string to, string msg,
            out string log, out string resume, out string error,
            bool checkcertificate = true, bool trystartssl = true)
        {

            #region check parameters

            log = Environment.NewLine;
            error = "";
            resume = "";
            string _fromaddrstr = "";
            string _toaddrstr = "";

            string _errorResume = $"[FAIL] Port={port}, Force SSL={forceSsl}, try STARTSSL={trystartssl}";

            System.Net.Mail.MailAddress addr = null;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(login))
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
                {
                    error = "If login is not empty than the password cannot be empty";
                    log += "!! Error : " + error;
                    resume = Environment.NewLine + $"[FAIL] 'password' is missing" + Environment.NewLine;
                    return false;
                }
            }

            try
            {
                addr = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(from);
                _fromaddrstr = addr.Address;
            }
            catch
            {
                error = "'from' email address is incorrect.";
                log += "!! Error : " + error;
                resume = Environment.NewLine + $"[FAIL] 'from' incorrect format > '{from}'" + Environment.NewLine;
                return false;
            }

            try
            {
                addr = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(to);
                _toaddrstr = addr.Address;
            }
            catch
            {
                error = "'to' email address is incorrect.";
                log += "!! Error : " + error;
                resume = Environment.NewLine + $"[FAIL] 'to' incorrect format > '{to}'" + Environment.NewLine;
                return false;
            }

            

            #endregion

            try
            {
                #region support variables

                string _response = "";
                string _msgfotter = "";

                StreamReader clearTextReader = null;
                StreamWriter clearTextWriter = null;

                StreamReader sslreader = null;
                StreamWriter sslwriter = null;

                SslStream sslStream = null;

                // Depending on checkcertificate value stream may ignore Certificate Errors
                // like: Hostname not in the certificate and Certificate Chain Errors 
                SslStream GetSslStream(Stream innerstream)
                {
                    if (checkcertificate)
                        return new SslStream(innerstream);
                    else
                        return new SslStream(
                            innerstream,
                            false,
                            new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback((s, c, h, e) => true),
                            null
                    );
                }

                #endregion

                #region support internal methods

                void ExitError(string str, ref string _log, ref string _error)
                {
                    _error = str;
                    _log += "!! Error : " + str + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
                    if (sslStream == null)
                    {
                        clearTextWriter.WriteLine("QUIT");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sslwriter.WriteLine("QUIT");
                    }


                }

                string AskReceive(string commandline, ref string _log)
                {
                    if (sslStream == null)
                    {
                        _log += "> " + commandline + Environment.NewLine;
                        clearTextWriter.WriteLine(commandline);

                        string _str;

                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);

                        //while (!clearTextReader.EndOfStream)
                        //while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_str))
                        //    {
                        //    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
                        //    //yield return _str;
                        //    _str = clearTextReader.ReadLine();
                        //    _log += "< " + _str + Environment.NewLine;
                        //}
                        _str = clearTextReader.ReadLine();
                        _log += "< " + _str + Environment.NewLine;

                        return _str;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _log += "> " + commandline + Environment.NewLine;
                        sslwriter.WriteLine(commandline);
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
                        string _str = sslreader.ReadLine();
                        _log += "< " + _str + Environment.NewLine;
                        return _str;
                    }
                }

                bool Login(ref string _log, ref string _error)
                {
                    if (!(_response = AskReceive($"AUTH LOGIN", ref _log)).StartsWith("334"))
                    {
                        ExitError(_response, ref _log, ref _error);
                        return false;
                    }

                    if (!(_response = AskReceive(Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{login}")), ref _log)).StartsWith("334"))
                    {
                        ExitError(_response, ref _log, ref _error);
                        return false;
                    }

                    if (!(_response = AskReceive(Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{password}")), ref _log)).StartsWith("235"))
                    {
                        ExitError(_response, ref _log, ref _error);
                        return false;
                    }

                    return true;
                }

                bool SendMsg(ref string _log, ref string _error)
                {

                    // HELO JakesDominoApp
                    // MAIL FROM: jake@jakehowlett.com
                    // RCPT To: jhowlett@EITS
                    // DATA
                    // From: My Self <me@you.com>
                    // To: A secret list <you@me.com>
                    // Subject: A simple test
                    // Mime-Version: 1.0;
                    // Content-Type: text/html; charset="ISO-8859-1";
                    // Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit;
                    //
                    // <html>
                    // <body>
                    // <h2>An important link to look at!</h2>
                    // Here's an <a href="http://www.codestore.net">important link</a>
                    // </body>
                    // </html>
                    // .
                    // QUIT

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(login))
                        if (!Login(ref _log, ref _error))
                            return false;


                    if (!(_response = AskReceive($"MAIL FROM: <{_fromaddrstr}>", ref _log)).StartsWith("250"))
                    {
                        ExitError(_response, ref _log, ref _error);
                        return false;
                    }

                    if (!(_response = AskReceive($"RCPT TO: <{_toaddrstr}>", ref _log)).StartsWith("250"))
                    {
                        ExitError(_response, ref _log, ref _error);
                        return false;
                    }

                    string _return = AskReceive($"DATA", ref _log);

                    if (_return.Substring(0, 1) == "5")
                    {
                        ExitError(_return, ref _log, ref _log);
                        return false;
                    }

                    string _details = $"Server:'{server}' | Login:'{login}' | port:{port} | try STARTTSL:{trystartssl} | Force SSL:{forceSsl}";

                    if (!AskReceive(
                        $"From: {from}" + Environment.NewLine +
                        $"To: {to}" + Environment.NewLine +
                        $"Subject: " + _details +
                        Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
                        msg + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
                        "__________________________________________________" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
                        _details + " " + _msgfotter + Environment.NewLine +
                        Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + ".", ref _log).StartsWith("250"))
                    {
                        ExitError(_response, ref _log, ref _error);
                        return false;
                    }

                    AskReceive($"QUIT", ref _log);
                    return true;

                }

                #endregion

                #region method body

                TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

                //Make the connection with timeout
                if (!client.ConnectAsync(server, port).Wait(connectionTimeout))
                {
                    //log = ex.ExceptionToString();
                    error = $"Could not connect '{server}' at port '{port}'";
                    log += Environment.NewLine + error + Environment.NewLine;
                    resume = Environment.NewLine + $"[FAIL] Port={port}. Could not connect '{server}' at port '{port}'" + Environment.NewLine;
                    return false;
                }

                using (client)
                {

                    if (forceSsl)
                    {
                        using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
                        using (sslStream = GetSslStream(stream)) // new SslStream(stream))
                        {
                            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(server);

                            using (sslreader = new StreamReader(sslStream))
                            using (sslwriter = new StreamWriter(sslStream) { AutoFlush = true })
                            {
                                log += Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "## SSL connection (safe)" + Environment.NewLine;
                                string connectResponse = sslreader.ReadLine();
                                log += "< " + connectResponse + Environment.NewLine;
                                if (!connectResponse.StartsWith("220"))
                                {
                                    ExitError(_response, ref log, ref error);
                                    resume = Environment.NewLine + $"[FAIL] Port={port}, Force SSL={forceSsl} (encrypted)";
                                    return false;
                                }

                                if (!(_response = AskReceive($"HELO {Dns.GetHostName()}", ref log)).StartsWith("250"))
                                {
                                    ExitError(_response, ref log, ref error);
                                    resume = Environment.NewLine + $"[FAIL] Port={port}, Force SSL={forceSsl} (encrypted)";
                                    return false;
                                }

                                _msgfotter = $"Encrypted MSG using SMTP/S on port: {port}";

                                if (SendMsg(ref log, ref error))
                                { resume = Environment.NewLine + $"[SUCCESS] Port={port}, Force SSL={forceSsl} (encrypted)"; return true; }
                                else
                                { resume = Environment.NewLine + $"[FAIL] Port={port}, Force SSL={forceSsl} (encrypted)"; return false; }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else //Not SMTP/S (SSL)
                    {
                        using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
                        using (clearTextReader = new StreamReader(stream))
                        using (clearTextWriter = new StreamWriter(stream) { AutoFlush = true })

                        {
                            log += Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "## Plain text connection (UNSAFE)" + Environment.NewLine;
                            string connectResponse = clearTextReader.ReadLine();
                            log += "< " + connectResponse + Environment.NewLine;
                            if (!connectResponse.StartsWith("220"))
                            {
                                ExitError(connectResponse, ref log, ref error);
                                resume = Environment.NewLine + $"[FAIL] Port={port}, Force SSL={forceSsl} (unsafe, plain text)";
                                return false;
                            }

                            if (!(_response = AskReceive($"HELO {Dns.GetHostName()}", ref log)).StartsWith("250"))
                            {
                                ExitError(_response, ref log, ref error);
                                resume = Environment.NewLine + $"[FAIL] Port={port}, Force SSL={forceSsl} (unsafe, plain text)";
                                return false;
                            }

                            if (trystartssl)
                            {
                                if ((_response = AskReceive("STARTTLS", ref log)).StartsWith("220"))
                                {
                                    clearTextReader = null;
                                    clearTextWriter = null;
                                    using (sslStream = GetSslStream(stream)) // new SslStream(stream))
                                    {

                                        //TLS Start
                                        sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(server);
                                        log += Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "## TLS connection (safe)" + Environment.NewLine;
                                        using (sslreader = new StreamReader(sslStream))
                                        using (sslwriter = new StreamWriter(sslStream) { AutoFlush = true })
                                        {
                                            if (!AskReceive($"HELO {Dns.GetHostName()}", ref log).StartsWith("250"))
                                            { ExitError(_response, ref log, ref error); resume = $"[FAIL] Port={port}, Force SSL={forceSsl} (encrypted)"; return false; }

                                            _msgfotter = "Encrypted MSG using STARTSSL on port: " + port.ToString();
                                            if (SendMsg(ref log, ref error))
                                            {
                                                resume = Environment.NewLine +
                                                    $"[SUCCESS] Port={port}, Force SSL={forceSsl}, try STARTSSL={trystartssl} (encrypted)";
                                                return true;
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                resume = Environment.NewLine +
                                                    $"[FAIL] Port={port}, Force SSL={forceSsl}, try STARTSSL={trystartssl} (encrypted)";
                                                return false;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            if ((trystartssl && !_response.StartsWith("220")) || !trystartssl)
                            {

                                if (trystartssl)
                                    log += "## Does not accept StartSSL" + Environment.NewLine;

                                _msgfotter = "Unsafe MSG using plain text on port: " + port.ToString();

                                if (SendMsg(ref log, ref error))
                                {
                                    resume = Environment.NewLine +
                                        $"[SUCCESS] Port={port}, Force SSL={forceSsl}, try STARTSSL={trystartssl} (unsafe, plain text)";
                                    return true;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    resume = Environment.NewLine +
                                        $"[FAIL] Port={port}, Force SSL={forceSsl}, try STARTSSL={trystartssl} (unsafe, plain text)";
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }

                            return false;

                        }
                    }

                }

                #endregion

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.Message == @"The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.")
                {
                    log += $"The host name '{server}' must exist in the server SSL certificate. Don't use IP or host names not in the Certificate" + Environment.NewLine;
                }
                error = ex.Message;
                log += "!! Error : " + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine;
                resume += Environment.NewLine + _errorResume;

                return false;
            }

            
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: @ rui-caramalho Go to abv.bg, create user and test to show as the result please. Please for God, somebody to tell me why server response is time outing always?

Comment: You create a user and a pass for me then send me the: email address, user and pass. That's the most I can do. They are not allowing new accounts.

Comment: But you can use my above code... copy to your project then call: `string _log = CommonCore.Tests.SmtpSeverProbe("username","password","smtp.abv.bg","yourgmail@gmail.com","Email test",out string fulllog, out string error, "yourABVemail.@abv.bg")`. Then see the '_log' value. Check the 'fulllog' for all the details if necessary.

Comment: https://network-tools.webwiz.net/mail-server-test.htm